# Is the partial sum of a Fourier series considered a orthogonal projection?

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

So my lecture notes claims that you can think of the partial Fourier series as a orthogonal projection of f onto a subspace spanned by the orthonormal basis vectors $e_{j}$

$f_{N}=\sum_{j-n}^{n}\left \langle f,e_{j} \right \rangle e_{j}(t)$.

Now the thing i dont get is why it is considered an orthogonal projection? Maybe im not understanding the concept of an orthogoanl projection correctly but wouldnt $\left \langle f,e_{j} \right \rangle=0$ if f and e were orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f_N$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ from your original Hilbert space $H$ to the subspace $H_N$ spanned by $e_{-N},e_{-N+1},\ldots,e_{N-1},e_N$. What this means is that
$f_N\in H_N$ and that $f-f_N$ is orthogonal to every element of $H_N$. That means
that $\langle f-f_N,e_j\rangle=0$ for $-N\le j\le N$, which is immediate from the formula
defining $F_N$.